# How to fix the HTTP 401 error even though all requests are permitted in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring Boot and have been working on Spring Security. I have a few exposed REST API end points that I am able to hit when tested on Postman. However, once I add spring-security and enablewebsecurity, I am not able to access the endpoint as I get a 401 error.

I have tried overriding the configure function with the web.ignore.antMatcher(HttpMethods.GET) function however the issue persists.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        httpSecurity
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Expected Result: A string returned on hitting "/welcome". This works when spring security is removed from the dependency and the configuration file with the above code is removed.

Actual Result : 401 Error. Message: Unauthorized. Error: Unauthorized

Comment: Do you make sure `SecurityConfiguration` can be scanned by spring ?

Comment: Can you make a minimal proof-of-concept project on Github?

Comment: what does `httpBasic()` do?  ;)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov the httpBasic lets use do basic authentication so it lets us send a username and password to authenticate us. basic authentication is base64 encoded

Comment: @EugenCovaci 

https://github.com/vj6978/SpringSecurity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `config` package and it's content to `com.example.demo` package because, right now, it is outside Spring Boot's scanning. See [Structuring Your Code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) documentation.

Here is a typical layout:

```
com
 +- example
     +- myapplication
         +- Application.java
         |
         +- customer
         |   +- Customer.java
         |   +- CustomerController.java
         |   +- CustomerService.java
         |   +- CustomerRepository.java
         |
         +- order
             +- Order.java
             +- OrderController.java
             +- OrderService.java
             +- OrderRepository.java
```

As you can see the main class and the packages-to-scan are at the same level.

Comment: Thank You Sir! It was a stupid mistake and I should've been more vigilant! Anyway thank you so much! Peace :)